# How do you check a token stored in a cache in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, token, bearer-token

so i am trying to check if a token exits in a cache but im not sure how to do so.
Before i create the token and store it into the cache i want to check if it exists, if it exists i want to be able to use the same token instead of creating a new one.

This is my code to create the token

```
public async Task<ResponseHandler> ExecuteAsync(XCommand command)
{
   
    string token;
    ResponseHandler resp = new ResponseHandler();
    
    
         token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

        await CacheService.Cache(true, typeof(bool), token, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
      
   // and then do something with the token
    return resp;

}
```

so this is what i tried

```
public async Task<VoucherResponseHandler> ExecuteAsync(VoucherCommand command)
{
    
    string token;
    ResponseHandler resp = new ResponseHandler();
    
    if (_distributedCacheService.Retrieve(token) == null) // i cant get it to check the token if its present it says use of unassigned local variable
    {
         token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

        await CacheService.Cache(true, typeof(bool), token, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
      
    }
    else { 
    }

    return resp;
}
```

Comment: You're not assigning anything to `token`, so when you call `RetrieveToken` the variable in uninitialized.

Comment: i tried to do it here Cache(true, typeof(bool), token, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
,so i dont know how to get this same token back

Comment: You'' need to send the token back to the client so that they can send it back to you at a later point. You can do this either using http headers (I think) or including the token as part of the response.

Comment: i actually have to make a post method to the client to obtain the token, but before i obtain the token i needed to know if the token exists.. so with the above i was trying a demo to find out how to read the token before actually making a request